# SAXParser '&' concatenation problem

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am presently using SAXParser with SAXParserFactory, and I have run into a problem with strings being cuttoff at '&' symbols. For example: "Nation Created Our World & everything in it" becomes "everything in it".

Obviously, I dont want this to happen. In the xml input, the character is properly escaped as `&amp;`. How can I resolve this?

```
try{
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
            XMLReader r = sp.getXMLReader();

            //This handles the xml and populates the entries array
            XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();


            // register event handlers
            r.setContentHandler(handler);
            String url = "http://foobar.xml";
            r.parse(url);

            return handler.getEntries();
}
```

I have this in my DefaultHandler class

```
....
    public void characters( char ch[], int start, int length ){
           String value = new String( ch , start , length );

           if(!value.trim().equals("")) {

               if( currentElement.equalsIgnoreCase("TITLE") ) {
                   tempEntry.setTitle(value);
               }
....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SAX API does not guarantee that any given text node will be delivered in one piece. It is permitted to break it up into multiple calls to the `characters()` method. Your application has to accommodate this possibly, and reassemble the pieces itself.

Incidentally, `Nation Created Our World & everything in it` is not a valid XML text fragment, it would have to be `Nation Created Our World &amp; everything in it`. In this case the SAX parser may be breaking it up into `Nation Created Our World`, `&amp;` and `everything in it`, and your app is only remembering the last one.

Comment: my mistake, but it is 'Nation Created Our World &amp; everything in it' in the XML file. I will try what you suggested

Answer (score 3):

Thanks skaffman

Implementation,

```
public void startElement(String s, String s1, String elementName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // clear tmpValue on start of element
    tmpValue = "";
}

public void characters(char[] ac, int i, int j) throws SAXException {
    tmpValue += new String(ac, i, j);
}
```