# ListView Data spliting into another row after Sax parsing

Tags: java, android, listview, row, saxparser

I am getting wrong listview data. I am using SAX parsing to get data from Web-service. Service is good, but I don't know where the mistake is?
Here my code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SaxParserDemoActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ArrayList<String> al_sno=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al_sname=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al_sclass=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al_sphno=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al_semail=new ArrayList<String>();

    SAXParserFactory spf;
    SAXParser sp;
    XMLReader xr;   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try{


            spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            sp=spf.newSAXParser();
            xr=sp.getXMLReader();

            URL sourceUrl = new URL(
            "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


            MyHandler mh=new MyHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(mh);

            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

            //.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.main);
            setListAdapter(new MyAdapter());





        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return al_sclass.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v=li.inflate(R.layout.second, null);

            TextView tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            tv1.setText(al_sno.get(arg0));

            TextView tv2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            tv2.setText(al_sname.get(arg0));



            return v;
        }

    }

    class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler{
        boolean is_sno=false;
        boolean is_sname=false;


        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.startDocument();
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);
            if(localName.equals("ID")){
                is_sno=true;
            }
            else if(localName.equals("Name")){
                is_sname=true;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.characters(ch, start, length);
            if(is_sno){
                al_sno.add(new String(ch,start,length));
            }
            else if(is_sname){
                al_sname.add(new String(ch,start,length));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
                throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.endElement(uri, localName, name);

            if(localName.equals("ID")){
                is_sno=false;
            }
            else if(localName.equals("Name")){
                is_sname=false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.endDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

My output screen:

[image: Screen].

You can see here "Alabama A&M" is splitting into 3 rows.

My logcat is

```
11-27 11:56:15.516: D/PhoneWindow(429): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40549d60 has no id.
11-27 11:56:15.976: D/dalvikvm(429): GC_CONCURRENT freed 218K, 50% free 2958K/5831K, external 1064K/1413K, paused 17ms+4ms
11-27 11:56:17.876: V/tea(429): Air Force
11-27 11:56:17.929: V/tea(429): Akron
11-27 11:56:17.946: V/tea(429): Alabama
11-27 11:56:17.986: V/tea(429): Alabama A
11-27 11:56:17.996: V/tea(429): &
11-27 11:56:18.036: V/tea(429): M
11-27 11:56:18.046: V/tea(429): Alabama State
11-27 11:56:18.066: V/tea(429): Albany
11-27 11:56:18.156: V/tea(429): Air Force
11-27 11:56:18.166: V/tea(429): Akron
11-27 11:56:18.196: V/tea(429): Alabama
11-27 11:56:18.229: V/tea(429): Alabama A
11-27 11:56:18.246: V/tea(429): &
11-27 11:56:18.274: V/tea(429): M
11-27 11:56:18.286: V/tea(429): Alabama State
11-27 11:56:18.326: V/tea(429): Albany
11-27 11:56:18.376: V/tea(429): Air Force
11-27 11:56:18.396: V/tea(429): Akron
11-27 11:56:18.426: V/tea(429): Alabama
11-27 11:56:18.456: V/tea(429): Alabama A
11-27 11:56:18.467: V/tea(429): &
11-27 11:56:18.504: V/tea(429): M
11-27 11:56:18.526: V/tea(429): Alabama State
11-27 11:56:18.636: V/tea(429): Albany
11-27 11:56:18.756: D/dalvikvm(429): GC_CONCURRENT freed 173K, 48% free 3188K/6023K, external 1056K/1413K, paused 19ms+6ms
11-27 11:56:19.097: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed com.ei.s/.Teamlist: +3s566ms
```

My XML Data is...

```
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
    <ID>47</ID>
    <Name>Akron</Name>
    </Table>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
    <ID>73</ID>
    <Name>Alabama</Name>
   </Table>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
    <ID>356</ID>
    <Name>Alabama A&M</Name>
   </Table>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
    <ID>187</ID>
    <Name>Alabama State</Name>
    </Table>
```

I am getting correct data in WEB-Service but not in Android app. Please help me that where I am making mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below(modifying your `MyHandler` class) should keep your node text together:

```
    // a field in the MyHandler class:
    boolean mIsSegment = false;
    // ...
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        if (is_sno) {
            al_sno.add(new String(ch, start, length));
        } else if (is_sname) {
            if (!mIsSegment) {
                al_sname.add(new String(ch, start, length));
            } else {
                al_sname.set(al_sname.size() - 1,
                        al_sname.get(al_sname.size() - 1)
                                + new String(ch, start, length));
            }
            mIsSegment = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.endElement(uri, localName, name);

        if (localName.equals("ID")) {
            is_sno = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("Name")) {
            is_sname = false;
            mIsSegment = false;
        }

    }
    // ...
```

The `SAXParser` is breaking the name text in multiple pieces and you're adding each of this pieces as a single item in the list. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354811/saxparser-concatenation-problem). Also there is no reason to call `setListdapter` twice(just call it once at the end of the `onCreate` method).

Comment: but how to keep particular table data in particular row?

Comment: how to filter Null values in list?

Comment: @tejaprakash Please start new questions regarding what you're asking providing more details. For example I don't understand what do you mean by *how to keep particular table data in particular row*. Filter `null` values when parsing or at a later time?

Comment: please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602752/xml-empty-tags-using-sax-parsing)

Comment: and one more question is how to do concatenation process for multiple XML strings in characters[]?

Comment: Hi Luksprog, above code not working for multiple string tags.can u tell me how? please...

Comment: @tejaprakash Once again please post a new question with more details related to the problem. I'm referring specially at how the xml file looks like. Also you should try to think and try to anticipate how the xml file looks so I may come with a solution that takes in consideration all possible problems instead of just some specific cases.

Comment: Hi Luksprog, Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622123/concatenation-error-in-sax-parser-android).